# Stellar JS directive in Angular JS

Tags: jquery, angularjs, plugins, parallax

I'm trying to create a directive to run Stellar JS plugin in my Angular JS application.

Here's what I tought:

```
app.directive('stellar', function() {
    return function (scope, element, attrs) {
        element.stellar({
            parallaxBackgrounds: true
        })
    }
});
```

and use it like this:

```
<div stellar></div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

I get no error in console...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know stellar but i know that you got an AngularJS plugin to use it with directives :) :
https://github.com/Pleasurazy/angularjs-stellar

I think that you should use it, it's always better to use existing library or plugins.

Hope it helps

Anyway try this :

```
app.directive('stellar', function() {
    return {
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            element.stellar({
                parallaxBackgrounds: true
            })
        }
     }
});
```

You have to return an object that implements "link" or "compil" function in AngularJS directive. For more information read the docs : http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Comment: I tried to implement, but with no success.

`app.directive('stellar', function() {
    return {
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            element.stellar({
                parallaxBackgrounds: true,
                responsive: true,
                verticalOffset: 100
            })
        }
    }
});`

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that the stellar part is good ? Make a plunkr please